# Cranial nerve ganglion, or Cranial nerve nucleus?

Tags: neuroscience, neuroanatomy, neuropsychology

I have a question that I hope some of you may be able to clarify for me.

I have been taught that dorsal root ganglia are analogous to cranial nerve ganglia except that dorsal root ganglion is located in the spinal cord vs. cranial nerve ganglion is located in the skull and is associated with a cranial nerve instead of spinal nerve. Now, what I am confused about and need clarification for is that if the terminology dictate that ganglia are outside the CNS, that is inside the PNS, and nuclei are inside the CNS and not in the PNS, why do we call cranial nerve ganglia ganglia instead of nuclei? Are these two used interchangeably, or am I missing something here?

Are cranial nerve ganglia and cranial nerve nuclei different?

Comment: Have you googled "cranial nerve ganglia"? Where are they located?

Comment: Hello Bryan, 

yes I have. The CNG are located in the brain stem.

Comment: According to which source?

Comment: Correction "The CG are located along the roots of cranial nerves V (trigeminal), VII (facial), IX (glossopharyngeal), and X (vagus) as they enter the brain stem" . Nuclei are located in the brainstem, however ganglia such as trigeminal ganglion are located outside and in this specific case, superficially to the temporal bone.

https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/B9780080450469006999

Comment: That statement does not say the ganglia are in the brain stem.

Comment: Yes, that is why I said Correction. I have corrected myself.

Comment: Gotcha - does that answer the question then?

Comment: Yes it does. Thank you.

Comment: If what you found answered your question, maybe you coukd formulate an answer with your sources.  You are free to answer your own questions on here. You could then get some reputation ranking on here from that

Comment: Excellent suggestion. I will do that.